# Is there a way to improve the algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm writing a simple game where a player has field of tiles of different colours. When chunk of similar tiles is picked it is removed. Remaining tiles slide down to empty spaces left by removed tiles.

The field itself is a 2d array and tile is tileSpr[x][y]

When tile is removed it has the value of null:

```
tileSpr[x][y] = null;
```

Now I have a very simple function that returns an array of tiles which need to be moved down along with how many 'holes' below they have:

```
whichTilesNeedMove() {
    const tilesToMove = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < CONFIG.maxRows; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < CONFIG.maxCols; j++) {
        if (this.tilesSpr[i][j] !== null) {
          let emptySpace = 0;
          for (let m = i - 1; m >= 0; m--) {
            if (this.tilesSpr[m][j] === null) {
              emptySpace++ ;
            }
          }
          if (emptySpace > 0) {
            tilesToMove.push({ tile: this.tilesSpr[i][j], emptySpace });

            this.tilesSpr[i - emptySpace][j] = this.tilesSpr[i][j];
            this.tilesSpr[i - emptySpace][j].rowIndex = i - emptySpace;
            this.tilesSpr[i][j] = null;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return tilesToMove;
  }
```

A feel that the algorithm used in the function is not optimal as it has to iterate over the whole 2d-array. Unfortunately nothing better comes to my mind as I'm quite a newbie in programming.

Could you suggest a more optimal way to do this?

Comment: what is `x` and `y` ? the coordinate of the top tile removed ? at what time you call `whichTilesNeedMove` ?

Comment: "When chunk of similar tiles is picked" -- at this point you already have all the info you need. You don't have to iterate again to find removed tiles.

Comment: how big are your CONFIG.maxRows, CONFIG.maxCols integers?

Comment: Now it's a 9x9 2d-array. maxRow = 9. maxCol = 9.

Comment: Some advise: organise your 2D array as an array of **columns** (instead of rows), where the first entry in a column-array is the square at the **bottom**. Then when a tile has to disappear, perform a `splice` on the corresponding column. This will automatically shift the upper tiles down. If really needed you can then `push` a `null` to that column to restore the total number of entries in it.

Comment: at my node.js runtime your algorithm is still at ca. 200ms for a 1000x1000 input array.

Comment: When you are removing a tile, that is the time when you know which column you have to check and starting from which row. After that this information is lost and traversing the entire table is what remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would organise the 2D array as an array of *columns* (instead of rows), where the first entry in a column-array is the square at the *bottom*. Then when a tile has to disappear, don't assign `null`, but perform a splice on the corresponding column. This will automatically shift the upper tiles down (in the model). If really needed, you can then push a null to that column to restore the total number of entries in it, but there is really no reason for that.

Here is a little demo. It uses CSS `transition` to animate the drops, but that is only decoration. It doesn't include the logic for finding tiles of the same color, but just removes the tile you click on, and updates the game area accordingly.

The core of my point is in the simplicity of the `push` and `splice` calls to keep the model (`game.columns`) updated.

```js
const delay = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
const transition = (elem, marginTop) => new Promise(resolve => {
    elem.style.marginTop = marginTop + "px";
    elem.ontransitionend = resolve
});

const game = {
    grid: document.querySelector("#grid"),
    columns: Array.from({length: 10}, () => []),
    async drop(x, color) {
        if (this.columns[x].length >= 10) return;
        const y = 10-this.columns[x].length;
        const tile = document.createElement("span");
        this.grid.append(tile);
        Object.assign(tile.style, { left: x * 20 + "px", backgroundColor: color });
        this.columns[x].push(tile);
        await delay(1);
        return transition(tile, y*20);
    },
    async remove(x, y) {
        if (y >= this.columns[x].length) return;
        this.columns[x].splice(y, 1)[0].remove();
        let p = Promise.resolve();
        for (let tile of this.columns[x].slice(y)) {
            p = transition(tile, (parseInt(tile.style.marginTop)+20));
        }
        return p;
    }
};

game.grid.onclick = function (e) {
    const x = Math.floor((e.clientX - this.offsetLeft) / 20);
    const y = 9 - Math.floor((e.clientY - this.offsetTop) / 20);
    game.remove(x, y)
}

async function initGame() {
    const randInt = (len) => Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
    const colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "grey", "cyan"];
    for (let i = 0; i < 70; i++) {
        game.drop(randInt(10), colors[randInt(colors.length)]);
        await delay(5);
    }
}

initGame();
```

```css
body { margin: 0 }
#grid>span { 
    position: absolute; 
    border: 1px solid; 
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 19px; 
    height: 19px;
    top: -20px;
    transition: margin-top 100ms linear;
}
#grid { 
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, lightgrey 1px, transparent 1px), 
                      linear-gradient(to bottom, lightgrey 1px, transparent 1px);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 201px;
    height: 201px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid"></div>
```

NB: The `drop` and `remove` methods return promises which resolve when the corresponding animation is complete, but I did not really use that return value in this snippet.

Comment: Thank you a lot for such a detailed answer and demo!

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate from the greates index and look if you got more null (here just for formatting with zero) values in a column and replace the most upper value with zero and the lower index with the value.

```js
var array = [
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 0, 0, 2],
        [3, 0, 0, 0, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 0, 0]
    ],
    i = array.length,
    j,
    l;

array.forEach(a => console.log(...a));    
console.log('to');

while (--i) {
    for (j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
        l = i;
        while (l > 0 && array[l][j] === 0) l--;
        if (l !== i) {
            array[i][j] = array[l][j];
            array[l][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

array.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try it